# Cannot upload an IMG file into PostGIS using raster2pgsql

Tags: postgis, raster, raster2pgsql

I cannot upload into PostGIS a raster with the following code:

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M "C:\lyr\gebco.img" -F public.gebco ¦ psql -d test -U postgres -W
```

It says ERROR: Unable to read raster file: public.gebco

Is it because of the sentence, or because of the configuration at my database? I don't know what to change.

Comment: Is your ERROR a one-liner? If not, please post the whole error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it with the specification of your address (localhost).

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M "C:\lyr\gebco.img" -F public.gebco | psql -h localhost -d test -U postgres
```

In addition to the address (localhost) you can specify the port as well: e.g. `-p 5432`

When your image is big you can tile it with `-t 100x100`. One tile represents 100x100 pixel. Tiling of very large rasters is recommended. This [link](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/blog/175/tiling-very-large-rasters) provides some useful information.

See also information for batch loading [here](http://dev.horizon.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/raster2pgsql.html) and [here](http://geospatialelucubrations.blogspot.de/2012/09/loading-many-rasters-into-separate.html).

Comment: Yes, It worked now by adding the localhost expression as you suggested. Cheers.